# How long does a pack of raw, dried Indian papad keep once opened?

Tags: storage-lifetime, indian-cuisine

How long does a pack of raw, dried Indian papad keep once it's opened? There's a best before date on the pack, but it's not mentioned how long they keep once it's opened. The ones I have are the [Lijjat Papad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lijjat_Papad) brand that's sold internationally. This stuff is pretty dry, so I'm guessing it will remain safe to eat for quite a while though.

Comment: Unsure, as I tend to use a whole pack at once, but I know that once they are cooked they go stale pretty quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't really experimented, but if imagining how dry that stuff is and the amount of salt that goes inside one those, I would say in the months/years range. Just keep it in a cool dry place..

Answer (score 3):

Air sealing it will do. Moisture affects papads for some reason.

Another tip : If you fry some papad, keeping them in air sealed bags will stop them from going mushy

Answer (score 2):

We store ours in the freezer in a ziploc bag (this prevents humidity from taking its toll). Lasts years without degradation (not sure how many -- certainly 3 or 4+).

Answer (score 0):

We’ve just used a pack that was bought, stored in our cool but dry cellar and forgotten since 2010. 12 years ago. We deep fried them on the weekend and they tasted great and crisp, just as they would with fresh papads. We passed them around at a family party where they were a big hit and three days later all of us are still alive, so I guess the papads can go a while…

Comment: But were they open? That's what the question asks about.  I suspect yours were sealed